# How can I use jQuery {{html}} tag inside {{each}} tag?

Tags: javascript, groovy, playframework

```
var visitMarkup = "<tr><td>{{each links}}{{html $value}}{{/each}}</td>\ </tr>";
```

I have an array of html links inside links variable. How can I decode the value using {{html}} tag inside {{each}} tag?

Comment: What does "decode" mean here?

Comment: @Tomalak It means HTML encode and decode because the values rendered by $ are HTML encoded if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Thanks. Always worth _clearly specifying_ these things in a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var visitMarkup = "{{each(linkIndex, link) links}}{{html link}}{{/each}}";
```

Comment: There's is no javascript error now but I have another problem. It creates this link <a href="undefined">[object Object]</a>. It doesn't create the correct one with values I want.

Comment: what is the type of link? Is it not a flat string? If not, then you need to specify the correct property of the object which has the URL. Make sure, you are passing in the correct array.